# Ionic tab with default page not in tab's stack

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, tabs

i spent a lot of time with this but couldn't find a way to make this work.

I have a Ionic 3 app with some pages accessible before login and some others after login. In my app.component i have the following code:

> app.component.ts

```
@Component({
templateUrl: 'app.html'
})

export class MyApp {
@ViewChild('rootNav') nav: NavController;

constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar,
            splashScreen: SplashScreen,
            private authService: AuthService,
            public translate: TranslateService) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
        // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
        // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
        statusBar.styleDefault();
        splashScreen.hide();
    });


    /* IF LOGGED IN GO TO HOMEPAGE */
    this.authService.isLoggedIn().then(data => {
        if (data) {
            this.nav.setRoot(TabsPage); // Another solutions is this.nav.setRoot(HomePage); but including tabs in the homepage returns error
        } else {
            this.nav.setRoot(LandingPage);
        }
    });
  }
}
```

This works perfectly but here comes the problem. I need 4 pages here, one is the "homepage" (showed for logged people) and other 3 pages reachable via tab click.

> tabs.component.ts

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'tabs.html'
}) 
export class TabsPage {
  @ViewChild('tabRef') tabRef: Tabs;
  root: TabsPage;
  tab1Root = HowItWorksPage;
  tab2Root = AboutPage;
  tab3Root = ContactPage;

  constructor() {

  }
}
```

> tabs.component.html

```
<ion-tabs #tabRef>
     <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" [tabTitle]="'requests' | translate" tabIcon="icon-requests"></ion-tab>
     <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" [tabTitle]="'offers' | translate" tabIcon="icon-offers"></ion-tab>
     <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" [tabTitle]="'services' | translate" tabIcon="icon-services"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

What i can't do is showing the tab page in the homepage without getting error or, as another solution, load the homepage as default tab (even if homepage is not a in the tab stack). I want to have this situation:

[image]

Thanks!